# Updating image using Put Request Cakephp Rest API

Tags: api, rest, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I am following Cakephp's Rest API docs to implement apis.[Cakephp Rest Api Docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html)

Please note I am using **Postman Rest Client** to test the apis.
As a requirement I need to provide the users to update a certain product image.

When I use `POST` Request to add images for the first time, I get the Image information in `$this->request->params['form']` array, which also has parameters like `name, type, tmp_name, error and size`.

```
    [form] => Array
    (
        [barcode_image] => Array
            (
                [name] => sitewide%20sales.png
                [type] => image/png
                [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpFCE8.tmp
                [error] => 0
                [size] => 136596
            )

        [image] => Array
            (
                [name] => phone%20number.png
                [type] => image/png
                [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpFCE9.tmp
                [error] => 0
                [size] => 89166
            )

    )
```

This can be easily tested in Postman by setting the field type to 'File'(which then lets you upload an image).

Now, I want to let users to Update the image which they had uploaded. For Updating i am using `PUT` request for which the required MIME type is `x-www-form-urlencoded`, this then prevents from updating a file.
How can I test updating of image in this scenario.

**Will I have to re-write the way i have implemented the API, so that Editing of the image(re-upload a new image) to be done using `POST` request?**

Any help will be greatly appreciated. If I am missing out any specifics, code please ask. I'll update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I googling for few minutes as per as of your problem. according to my point of you need to understand what is the purpose of `PUT`   &  `POST`.

Just Look at  [request->is('post') Vs request->is('put')](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cake-php/fbL1CJ1MAUg)